# On iOS, didDisconnectPeripheral callback not fired when Bluetooth is switched off by the user

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth

When the user switch off the Bluetooth, the centralManagerDidUpdateState callback is called

BUT the didDisconnectPeripheral callback is never fired

Is it the normal feature ?

Comment: Did you confirm the peripheral delegate in your class ?